# How to set inplace editors in XtraGrid separately in each row?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I am using XtraGrid Control using C#. I want to set inplace editors in XtraGrid separately in each row ie. separate editors for separate rows

See the following two images representing grid controls. I want such type of grid.

[image: following] 
[image: following]

Answer (score 1):

To implement first image, please use the [GridView.CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event:

```
void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if(e.Column.FieldName!="Value") return;
   GridView gv = sender as GridView;
   string editorName = (string)gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "EditorName");
   switch (editorName) {
      case "Spin Edit":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemSpinEdit1;
         break;
      case "Combo Box":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
         break;
      case "Check Edit":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
         break;
      //...
   }           
}
```

To implement second image use the [DevExpress PropertyGrid Control](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2462)